# Why is my code not giving me a graph? (finite difference method)

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

For a finite difference method code, I after altered it a bit for my needs. I am no longer getting errors, however I am not getting my graph to show.

```
Mx = 100;
My = 100;
Lx = Ly = 1.;
dx = Lx/Mx;
dy = Ly/My;
V[0, j_] = 0;
V[Mx, j_] = 1;
V[i_, 0] = 0;
V[i_, My] = 0;

p[i_, j_] = 0;

var = Flatten[Table[V[i, j], {i, 1, Mx - 1}, {j, 1, My - 1}]];

eqs = Flatten[
   Table[(V[i + 1, j] - 2 V[i, j] + 
        V[i - 1, j])/(dx)^2 + (V[i, j + 1] - 2 V[i, j] + 
        V[i, j - 1])/(dy)^2 , 
    p[i, j], {i, 1, Mx - 1}, {k, 1, My - 1}]];

sol = Solve[eqs, var][[1]];

Vsol = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{i dx, j  dy, V[i, j]}, {i, 0, Mx, Mx/10}, {j, 0, 
       My, My/10}] /. sol, 1]];

ContourPlot[Vsol[x, y], {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, 0, 0.05}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x(m)", "y(m)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Finite Difference Method Solution when p_v = 0"]
```

I am unsure for what I need to do here. Only thing I can think of is to maybe have all arguments be in terms of [i_ , j_] like in the declared variables part.

I know for this case (when p[i_, j_] = 0), I am to get a very similar solution as in this thread: [Not sure how to set up the Laplacian/Poisson Equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191984/not-sure-how-to-set-up-the-laplacian-poisson-equation)

Comment: What is the definition of `V[i_,j_]` ? As you note you need to define this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `Solve` returned `{}` due to several typos. This should work:

```
Mx = 100;
My = 100;
Lx = Ly = 1.;
dx = Lx/Mx;
dy = Ly/My;
ClearAll[V];
V[0, j_] = 0;
V[Mx, j_] = 1;
V[i_, 0] = 0;
V[i_, My] = 0;
p[i_, j_] = 0;
var = Flatten[Table[V[i, j], {i, 1, Mx - 1}, {j, 1, My - 1}]];
eqs = Flatten[
   Table[(V[i + 1, j] - 2 V[i, j] + 
         V[i - 1, j])/(dx)^2 + (V[i, j + 1] - 2 V[i, j] + 
         V[i, j - 1])/(dy)^2 == p[i, j], {i, 1, Mx - 1}, {j, 1, 
     My - 1}]];

sol = Solve[eqs, var][[1]];

Vsol = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{i dx, j dy, V[i, j]}, {i, 0, Mx}, {j, 0, My}] /. 
     sol, 1]];
```

This is however very inefficient. I would advise you to learn to use `SparseArray` in order to formulate this equations as a linear equation and to solve it with `LinearSolve`. That will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Haha, I definitely don't doubt that it was inefficient, this way made the most sense to me. However, I can't necessarily say I agree with the graph shown. I am doing the same problem as in the link to the thread I mentioned earlier. That solution was spot on in what I needed in that the top of the boundary was the value of 1, while in this case it seems to show that the corner has the value of 1 instead of the boundary.

EDIT: I also should note that when I have the value of 1 set for V[Mx, j_], the values according to the legend are off by a very large factor.

Comment: The order in which you enter the conditions `V[0, j_] = 0;
V[Mx, j_] = 1;
V[i_, 0] = 0;
V[i_, My] = 0;` is relevant; _Mathematica_ tries to use the most special definition but in this case, there are several definitions that would have the same precedence. In this case,  _Mathematica_ uses the definition that was entered first.

Comment: Yes, but when I have moved that value to the other boundaries, I'm still not getting a sensible graph. I have changed values of Mx, My, and p[i_, j_], but the graph is unchanging. However, increasing the values of Mx and My are giving me better values for the points, despite not changing how it looks.

Comment: That's another problem not related to the original question. (The sentence starting with "Yes, but..." is a good indicator for that.) As I said, this method is neither efficient nor robust, so I won't invest further time on fixing it. My suggestion to learn about `SparseArray` still holds.